# Country based databases in C# web application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-applications

Web application with MVC ->Currently I have a database with customer data and product details.
The application has been using in only one country. Now going to globally use the web application.

But the customers doesn't want their customer data leave out of their country. 
For example if we are going to support two countries, then we need to have two databases deployed(one for each).

So I am thinking to use WCF to get the data from two different countries and display the same in our Web application.

Do you have any other suggestion on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are going to create a new server in the other country? That seems like a pretty bizarre practice.

Comment: @SeanLange plus he will have to move to the said country to test the data as it cannot be accessible from another country. Very weird requirement indeed.

Comment: And even funnier is it is a web application. I am guessing that perhaps the stated requirements are not really what you mean.

Comment: I think the OP is even implying that they'll have a separate database for every country that they have involvement with. There's just under 200 countries in the world, so, if you were to deal with all of them (unlikely, but devil's advocate), are you saying you'd need just under 200 databases? That sounds like a nightmare to support. Personally, I just think you need to ensure good data segregation.

Comment: Can you just have one Database and improve its security...?
You can create users and control them as you please.

Comment: Guys. Thanks for the reply ! The requirement is to support 4 or 5 countries at the max.  And the idea is not to reveal the customer data to other countries even physically(database level). So I planned to break down the database into 2(one for customer data which will have 4 or 5 instances based on countries, and another for product data which is common) But from the web application, i need to access that common product database and the customer database based on the logged in user's region & do some operations and display the results. So for this, am planning to use WCF for this.Suggestions?

Comment: How are you determining the location of the user? Perhaps you might want to consider row level security. Separate databases isn't going to be a scalable solution, and still going to be difficult to maintain (imagine if you have to change the DDL for the databases and miss one, later on breaking your website when it doesn't function correctly for that country).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Larnu ! Row level security is good option to be considered. But the concern is since the customers doesnt want their database server move out of the country. So in this case of 3 countries for example, i need to have 3 servers with their country's customer data in it.  And the location of the user will be determined by having a flag for each application user with their region may be